# Highcharts determine if text is outside of data point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I’m wondering if there is a way to distinguish the data point being inside or outside of a bar.

Basically, with the chart below

- I want the text 9178 to be in a colour I generate (because it’s inside a bar)
- I want the rest of the numbers to be black (because they are outside of bars)

I’m wondering if the API provides something that I can use programmatically to decide what colour to use.
e.g. If a data point has a method isOverflow() that I can call, then I can set the colour to black if it returns true.

[image]

created on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mingzilla/pjqhqn4u/6

```
var generateColor = function(item) {
  var lightColor = "#DADADA";
  var color = new Highcharts.Color(item.point.color).rgba;
  var isLightBg = color[0] + color[1] + color[2] > 384;
  return isLightBg ? '#000000' : lightColor;
};


$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'I want data point inside a bar to be my colour, and outside to be black'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Car Insurance',
        'Life Insurance',
        'Pet Insurance'
      ]
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          overflow: 'justify',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            textShadow: 'none'
          },
          formatter: function() {
            var item = this;
            return '<span style="fill:' +
              generateColor(item) + '">' +
              (item.point.formattedValue || item.point.y) +
              '</span>';
          }
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      "color": "#666699",
      "name": "North",
      "data": [{
        "color": "#666699",
        "name": "Car Insurance",
        "y": 9178
      }, {
        "color": "#666699",
        "name": "Life Insurance",
        "y": 4518
      }, {
        "color": "#666699",
        "name": "Pet Insurance",
        "y": 1450
      }]
    }, {
      "color": "#663366",
      "name": "South",
      "data": [{
        "color": "#663366",
        "name": "Car Insurance",
        "y": 2129
      }, {
        "color": "#663366",
        "name": "Life Insurance",
        "y": 1066
      }, {
        "color": "#663366",
        "name": "Pet Insurance",
        "y": 374
      }]
    }]

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaulty the color is based on contrast or declared single color. But you can return a color (i.e black) for all datalabels. Then catch load / redraw events in the chart object to interate on all dataLabels. Inside each of them, there is information about position and verticalAlign, which can be used to check where label is. If this is top, apply your lightColor by css() method.

```
var lightColor = "#DADADA";

function datalabelColor() {
    var chart = this,
  series = chart.series,
  each = Highcharts.each,
  dL;

  each(series, function(serie, i) { 
    each(serie.data, function(p, j) {
      dL = p.dataLabel;

      if(dL.alignOptions.verticalAlign === 'top') {
        dL.css({
            color: lightColor
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Example:
- https://jsfiddle.net/mys5k9ty/

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: This works well. Thanks a lot. I was wondering why we have to do it on the load / redraw events, but I've just noticed dataLabel of a data point is not available at the time the dataLabels.formatter function is executed, so I'll have to engage with the load / redraw event like what you suggest. (this may benefit other users)